# R web-service for real-time prediction with online learning

Tags: gratis, library, machine-learning, r

What free framework or [R](http://www.r-project.org/) packages should I use to deploy R as a web service handling many models for real-time prediction (with online learning)?

It should be able to address those key points:

- Allow parallel processing/requests while handling a memory/cpu policy preventing reaching memory/cpu limits.
- Update many models in parallel safely (ie. prevent concurrent updates). able to quickly load/unload many models on a single machine because not all models (ie. >1000) could fit in memory.
- Handle large streams with low footprint (out-of-core).
- Able to use VowpalWabbit and StreamMOA R packages.
- Web service could be Http or Thrift based.